How to execute scripts or command while anyone install my software written in electron js on their OS
I have created a project using electron js, and now i want to make a linux distributable using electron forge make, but during installation of this software on any linux system i need to do execute this command:
sudo sed -i 's/^#[[:space:]]*\(WaylandEnable\)/\1/' /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

which will uncomment WaylandEnable and then my software can capture screenshot of the screen without asking user to pick again and again while taking screenshot, it is an activity monitoring software.
I don't know how to run this command on user's machine while he install my software, and once this command is executed and then the software is install i want to ask user to restart his system to use application.

Make sure not to build your application as an AppImage and the like, but rather use the operating system's package manager. This use-case is exactly why DEB, RPM and others have pre-install/post-install scripts.
These are shell scripts you may define for your package and which will be executed by the package manager before or after your application's package has been installed.
You can define these scripts to be used by Electron Forge in the DEB maker's configuration. Sadly, at the time of writing, Electron Forge only supports these scripts for Debian packages, so you won't be able to use this mechanism when you're building RPM packages for Fedora, RedHat, SUSE or OpenSUSE. If you'd need this, you could file an issue with the maintainers.
For Debian packages, your configuration snippet could look something like
{
  name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
  config: {
    options: {
      maintainer: 'YOUR NAME',
      homepage: 'https://example.com',
      scripts: {
        postinst: '/path/to/your/postinst.sh',
        postrm: '/path/to/your/postrm.sh'
      }
    }
  }
}

For more information, please consult Electron Forge's documentation I've linked to above.
Also, I recommend to backup the configuration file you're modifying (before you modify it, of course) to a well-specified location in your post-install script and possibly restore the version present on the system before the installation of your app to undo any changes made by your app's package. Though of course this could overwrite changes made by other software, but I consider it to be more rude for a software that I have uninstalled to not clean up after itself.
The other (and, in my opinion, better) option is to advise users how to make this configuration change themselves. It seems to me as though this is only a workaround for lazyness/convenience and your application could work without it. Therefore, I would not choose to alter my user's system configuration if they don't want that.
In any case, please make sure to let your users know that installing your package may change their GDM configuration.
